# Access VBA: Getting Value of Checkbox from Another Form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, controls

i'm trying to access the value of a checkbox I have in a separate form. I have no problem accessing the checkbox information from within it's own form using code...

```
If Not IsNull(Check43) Then
    If Check43 Then
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "Insert_Query"
    End If
End If
```

But I can't figure out how to access the value of "Check43" in another form. I thought something like below would work...

```
Dim frm As Form, ctl As Control
Set frm = Forms!Relevant_Application
Set ctl = frm!Check43

If Not IsNull(ctl) Then
    If ctl Then
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "Insert_Query"
    End If
End If
```

but even when the checkbox is checked, it doesn't work. It doesn't throw an error, it just skips over the function.

Comment: Looks ok. Are there subforms involved? [Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) -- Try stepping through the code and inspecting variables. [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Not necessary to use form and control object variables. If Check43 is in a subform, the path reference will be more complicated. The IsNull is also unnecessary. Is Check43 UNBOUND? Where are you calling this code?

Comment: Try `If (ctl) Then` or `If ctl = True Then`

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes do not store a null value, they store a boolean (-1 and 0). So if you change the logic from `If Not IsNull(ctl) Then` To `If ctl = True Then` it should work.

This was also addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813760/determine-whether-a-access-checkbox-is-checked-or-not).

To give credit where credit is due @BankBuilder did mention this before me.

Hope that helps.
Best Regards.